# part text inside tags python

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, text-extraction

I have a semi structured .txt file. The file looks like this:

```
<tags>
    blabla<text>
              I want this
         </text>
    blabla<text>
               And this
           </text>
        bla<text>
                 and this
            </text>blabla
</tags>
```

I want to get the text inside the `<text>` tags. I've managed to do it using string partition and replace but I don't think it is very efficient or pretty.

Here's my code:

```
with open('collection.txt') as f:
 read_data = f.read()

text1 = read_data.partition("<text>")[2].partition("</text>")[0]
temp1 = read_data.replace(text1,'').replace('<text>','',1).replace('</text>','',1)
text2 = temp1.partition("<text>")[2].partition("</text>")[0]
temp2 = read_data.replace(text2,'').replace('<text>','',2).replace('</text>','',2)
text3 = temp2.partition("<text>")[2].partition("</text>")[0]
```

BeautifulSoup, Element tree and other XML parsers didn't work.
Any suggestions on how to improve my code? I've tried compiling a regular expression, but to no avail.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I parse XML in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1912434/how-do-i-parse-xml-in-python)

Comment: Use regex! Its a bit of a learning curve if you haven't used it before, but definitely worth it for a project like this

Comment: @Aran-Fey I've tried those parsers including BeautifulSoup but I couldn't get it to work, maybe because the file is semi-structured?

Comment: @EriktheRed I think regex is how I want to solve it, but every regex I've tried so far prints blank.

Comment: what do you mean by semi-structured? what could not work?

Comment: regex is not recommended for structured / nested parsing. It will quickly fail for more complicated examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use BeautifulSoup as follows to get all the text entries:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

with open('collection.txt') as f:
    read_data = f.read()

soup = BeautifulSoup(read_data, 'xml')

for text in soup.find_all('text'):
    print(text.get_text(strip=True))
```

Giving you:

```
I want this
And this
and this
```

You should definitely **avoid** trying to use regular expressions for doing this kind of parsing as it will quickly fail for more complicated examples, e.g. if a comment is used such as `<!-- </text> -->` in the middle of your data, it should be ignored.

Comment: Thank you, this worked like a charm, I obviously implemented BeautifulSoup wrong.

Answer (score 3):

Use an XML parser, such as [`xml.etree`](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html) ([live demo](https://ideone.com/wg4jNM)):

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
doc = ET.parse('collection.txt')
print([el.text.strip() for el in doc.findall('.//text')])
# output: ['I want this', 'And this', 'and this']
```

Answer (score 1):

regex is your best friend!

---

```python
import re

p = re.compile(r'<text>([^</]*)</text>')
result = p.findall(data_txt)
result = [x.strip() for x in result]
print(result)
```

Comment: Why the `/` in the character class? ([Also: relevant note on using regex to parse XML/HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/35070))

Comment: Thanks a lot! That did the trick, it was the regex I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

```
re.findall('<text>\s*.*\s*</text>', data)
```

another solution for this